# developing app with windows8 for tablet,mobile,desktop

Tags: windows-8, desktop-application, tablet, mobile-application

I need develop an application for windows8 mobile,tablet,desktop.As  i am fresh to mobile app i dont have any idea about this.Is there anyway to develop an application like this with single code or we have to write code seperatly for all three and how to add this app to the app store. please anyone help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Typically, we use stackoverflow to answer specific questions about code issues you're having.  Despite this, please begin at some of the great instructional videos provided on Microsoft development centers (better known as MSDN).  They have quick-launch tutorials and the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps).